# How to transcribe more than 1 minute audio clip in cloud speech to text API?

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-speech

My problem is, I tried to transcribe less than one minute audio clip using Google Cloud and its work but when I tried more a minute it doesn't work. 
So my question is, How to transcribe more than a minute audio or without limitations?

Answer (score 0):

From https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas#content:

- Audio longer than ~1 minute must use the uri field to reference an audio file in Google Cloud Storage.

So, store the file in Google Storage before transcribing.

Comment: Can we not do it for local files? There must be some way

Comment: I don't believe so, instead upload and then transcribe.

Answer (score 0):

Transcribing short audio file using Synchronous speech recognition [Transcribing Short audio file](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/sync-recognize). If you audio file is longer than 1 minute then you use Asynchronous Speech Recognition.

Consider this example coming from this documentation [Transcribing long audio file](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-recognize#speech-async-recognize-gcs-gcloud). You may run the sample command below in Cloud Shell. You just have to upload [(how to upload objects to GCS)](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects) your audio file in GCS then use that as your input.

```
gcloud ml speech recognize-long-running \
'gs://gcs-test-data/vr.flac' \
 --language-code='en-US' --async

gcloud ml speech operations describe [OPERATION_ID]
```

Comment: Please be aware of the pricing 0 to 60 minutes (per month) is free of charge, anything in excess is charged accordingly 

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/pricing